Quadratic expression formed from the elements of the set $\mathbb A$ having integral roots.
This question is not the same as this, as this involves finding integral roots.
Question
Consider the set $\mathbb A =$ {$1,2,3,4....50$}. Choose a second degree polynomial $f(x)$, with all its coefficients being elements of the set $\mathbb A$. Now the question is how many such formed quadratic expressions have all its roots as integers?
My effort
I've chosen the polynomial to be $ax^2+bx+c$. It is obvious that
$$b^2-4ac\ge0$$ and $$b^2-4ac=k^2$$ It can also be noted that $k$ is also an element of $\mathbb A$. So, we must determine the no. of elements of $\mathbb A$ that satisfy the above equality. Here, I got stuck and don't know what to do further. Can we think of using generating functions to solve this problem? Also, if a solution can be formed, can this method be extended to any number of elements in the set $\mathbb A$? Thank you in advance for your time and effort.${}{}$
Edit1 $b+k$ and $b-k$ must be even, since $2a|b\pm k$(for integral roots)

Thanks for the clarification about how this is different to your earlier post. I have withdrawn my comment as a result of your update.

@user2661923 I'm not implying the roots are elements of $\mathbb A$, but just the discriminant

Yes, I realized my mistake and then deleted my comment.

Since the roots of $P=ax^2+bx+c$ are integers you have $a| b$ and $a| c$ so putting $b'=b/a$ and $c'=c/a$, the polynomial $x^2+b'x+c'$ has integer roots with $b',c'\in A$. : counting the polynomials $x^2+b'x+c'$ with coefficients$b',c'$  in $A$ that have integer roots is easier and each one gives you the polynomials $ax^2+ab'x+ac'$ having coefficients in $A$ as long as $ab', ac'\leqslant 50$.

@FredBernard Can you please explain why $a|b$ and $a|c$, as I'm just dumb to understand why.

The som of all roots is $-b/a$ and their product is $c/a$, that's why.

Let $a,b,c\in\Bbb{A}$ and suppose that the quadratic
$$ax^2+bx+c=0,\tag{1}$$
has integral roots, say $-u$ and $-v$. Then
$$ax^2+bx+c=w(x+u)(x+v),$$
for some integer $w$, and expanding the right hand side yields the identities
$$a=w,\qquad b=(u+v)w,\qquad c=uvw.$$
First note that $a,b,c>0$ and so $w>0$, $uv>0$ and $u+v>0$, from which it follows that $u,v>0$. This implies that $b':=\tfrac ba=u+v$ and $c':=\tfrac ca=uv$ are integers in $\Bbb{A}$, and hence that
$$x^2+b'x+c'=(x+u)(x+v),\tag{2}$$
is another quadratic with coefficients in $\Bbb{A}$ and integral roots. This shows that we can first count monic polynomials and then count their scalings that still have coefficients within $\Bbb{A}$.
The coefficients of $(2)$ are in $\Bbb{A}$ if and only if $u,v>0$ and $uv\leq50$ and $u+v\leq50$. Of course $u+v\leq uv$ unless $u=1$ or $v=1$, so if $uv\leq50$ then $u+v\leq50$ unless $\{u,v\}=\{1,50\}$.
Without loss of generality $u\leq v$ and so $u\leq7$ because $uv\leq50$. For each value of $u$ we have $v\leq\frac{50}{u}$ and so we count a total of count
$$\sum_{u=1}^7\big\lfloor\frac{50}{u}\big\rfloor-(u-1)=50+24+14+9+6+3+1=107,$$
pairs of positive integers $(u,v)$ with $u\leq v$ and $uv\leq50$. Excluding the pair $(1,50)$ we get a total of $106$ monic polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb{A}$ and integral roots.
In a similar fashion we can count the non-monic quadratic polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb{A}$ and integral roots. If the leading coefficient is $2$ then it is twice a monic polynomial with coefficients at most $25=\tfrac{50}{3}$, and $uv\leq25$ so $u\leq5$, so we get
$$\sum_{u=1}^5\lfloor\frac{25}{u}-(u-1)\rfloor=25+11+6+3+1=46,$$
pairs of positive integers $(u,v)$ with $u\leq v$ and $uv\leq25$. Excluding the pair $(u,v)=(1,25)$ we get a total of $45$ polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb{A}$ and integral roots, and leading coefficient $a=2$. For $a=3,\ldots,13$ we get
\begin{eqnarray}
a=3&:\qquad&\sum_{u=1}^4\lfloor\frac{16}{u}-(u-1)\rfloor&=&16+7+3+1&=&27,\\
a=4&:\qquad&\sum_{u=1}^3\lfloor\frac{12}{u}-(u-1)\rfloor&=&12+5+2&=&19,\\
a=5&:\qquad&\sum_{u=1}^3\lfloor\frac{10}{u}-(u-1)\rfloor&=&10+4+1&=&15,\\
a=6&:\qquad&\sum_{u=1}^2\lfloor\frac{8}{u}-(u-1)\rfloor&=&8+3&=&11,\\
a=7&:\qquad&\sum_{u=1}^2\lfloor\frac{7}{u}-(u-1)\rfloor&=&7+2&=&9,\\
a=8&:\qquad&\sum_{u=1}^2\lfloor\frac{6}{u}-(u-1)\rfloor&=&6+2&=&8,\\
a=9,10&:\qquad&\sum_{u=1}^2\lfloor\frac{5}{u}-(u-1)\rfloor&=&5+1&=&6,\\
a=11,12&:\qquad&\sum_{u=1}^2\lfloor\frac{4}{u}-(u-1)\rfloor&=&4+1&=&5,\\
a=13,\ldots,16&:\qquad&\sum_{u=1}^1\lfloor\frac{3}{u}-(u-1)\rfloor&&&=&3,\\
a=17,\ldots,25&:\qquad&\sum_{u=1}^1\lfloor\frac{3}{u}-(u-1)\rfloor&&&=&2,\\
\end{eqnarray}
and as before, in each case we discard the pair $(u,v)=(1,v_{\text{max}})$. This yields a total of
$$106+45+26+18+14+10+8+7+2\times5+2\times4+4\times2+9\times1=269,$$
quadratic polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb{A}$ and integral roots.
